# Other div on the same row moves during float (Flexgrid implementation)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am having hard time adjusting the alignment the the rest of div's whenever I attempt to float one from that row. Below is what I meant, attached is a sample snippet.

```css
.flex-grid {
  display: flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}
.flex-grid .rcorners1 {
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: green;
    padding: 10px; 
    width: 21.5%;
    height: 145px;    
 padding: 16px;
    margin: .50em 0;
 z-index:0;
 position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}
.flex-grid .rcorners2 {
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: green;
    padding: 10px; 
    width: 28%;
    height: 200px;    
 top:180px;
 padding: 16px;
    margin: .50em 0;
 z-index:1;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;  
    border-color:#a6a6a6;
 position:absolute;
 overflow: hidden;
 overflow-x: hidden; 
    z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-grid">
  <div class="rcorners1">Sample</div>
  <div class="rcorners1">Sample</div>
  <div class="rcorners1">Sample</div>
  <div class="rcorners1">Sample</div>
</div>
<div class="flex-grid">
  <div class="rcorners1">Sample</div>
  <div class="rcorners1">Sample</div>
  <div class="rcorners1">Sample</div>
  <div class="rcorners1">Sample</div>
</div>
<div class="flex-grid">
  <div class="rcorners1">Sample</div>
  <div class="rcorners2">Sample Selected</div>
  <div class="rcorners1">Sample</div>
  <div class="rcorners1">Sample</div>
</div>
```

Notice that on the third row when the div (Sample Selected) was on float , the remaining div's got misaligned. Please notice the huge space from third row. Seems that when the selected div was on float, remaining div's adjust to take some of the spaces of the selected floating div.

Any idea how can I align the remaining div's from that row so that it can get align with the rest?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you give an element `position: absolute` you remove it from the document flow. This means that it no longer occupies space in the container and surrounding elements don't even know it exists.

That's why your third row is being re-aligned. When one of the four elements ("Sample Selected") is absolutely positioned, the siblings adjust to the new empty space.

You could try using `position: relative` instead, which doesn't remove elements from the document flow.

```css
.flex-grid {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex-grid .rcorners1 {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 21.5%;
  height: 145px;
  padding: 16px;
  margin: .50em 0;
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.flex-grid .rcorners2 {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 28%;
  height: 200px;
  top: -250px; /* ADJUSTED */
  right: 250px; /* NEW */
  padding: 16px;
  margin: .50em 0;
  z-index: 1;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: #a6a6a6;
  position: relative; /* ADJUSTED */
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-grid">
  <div class="rcorners1">Sample</div>
  <div class="rcorners1">Sample</div>
  <div class="rcorners1">Sample</div>
  <div class="rcorners1">Sample</div>
</div>
<div class="flex-grid">
  <div class="rcorners1">Sample</div>
  <div class="rcorners1">Sample</div>
  <div class="rcorners1">Sample</div>
  <div class="rcorners1">Sample</div>
</div>
<div class="flex-grid">
  <div class="rcorners1">Sample</div>
  <div class="rcorners2">Sample Selected</div>
  <div class="rcorners1">Sample</div>
  <div class="rcorners1">Sample</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pLuye06k/

Comment: thanks for taking time. Upon checking, I saw that the two divs from the right where the div float came from have some sort of overlap. I'll try to play around it maybe I'm actually near to solving this. Thanks @michael_B

Comment: This looks like a good candidate for CSS Grid Layout:  https://jsfiddle.net/pLuye06k/1/

Comment: thanks for giving another option, I tried it (the sample) on ie11  seems not supported? anyways thanks for taking time again.